# Scrolling DIV, I want a DIV inside of it with 100% Height

Tags: html, css

I have a div that scrolls, and there is a div inside of it that I wanted to set 100% height to. It's not working, though. Here is my code:

```css
.column {
  float: right;
  width: 88%;
  max-height: 430px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.detailed {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background: #fff;
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="detailed"></div>
</div>
```

Edit Note: It was just a spelling error. The main document has the correct spelling and everything. I was tired.

Comment: First of all fix the syntax ```class="column"``` and you have written styling for "detailed" class and there is no such class.

Comment: Aside from @aavrug 's comments, could you be a bit more specific with what you're looking for?

Comment: The left, right and bottom are necessary to position it. It works. It won't position otherwise. The class names were a mistake. I was tired, but they are correct on the main document.

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0q1jy877/

```
.column {
  float: right;
  width: 88%;
  max-height: 430px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.details {
  background: #fff;
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

<div class="column">
   <div class="details"></div>
</div>
```

Your html div with class "column" was missing a quotation mark, and you used the  ".detailed" class in your css but ".details" class in your html so it didn't match up.

Apart from that I basically just removed the position & top/left/bottom/right properties as they weren't necessary for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this can be achieved. I personally like using the simple method in which I used when creating responsive iframes and the result would be the same regardless of content.

I simply add a

```
padding-bottom: 56.25%
```

I also added a white background so you can see the height, and keep in mind you have your main container set to 430px.

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/636m15dj/1/